# PCL make not generating kinfu_large_scale

Tags: point-cloud-library

This is being built on a [Nvidia Jetson TK1](http://elinux.org/Jetson_TK1) (armv7). I have installed `Cuda` v6.5, `OpenNi` v1 & v2, and `SensorKinect`. I have the following options set via `ccmake` prior to the build:

- BUILD_CUDA
- BUILD_GPU
- BUILD_apps
- BUILD_examples
- CUDA_HOST_COMPILER: /usr/bin/cc
- CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR:  /usr/local/cuda-6.5

Here is the output of make:

```
$ make
-- Using CPU native flags for SSE optimization:  -march=native
-- -- GCC > 4.3 found, enabling -Wabi
-- Found OpenMP
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3, version: 3.2.0)
-- FLANN found (include: /usr/include, lib: optimized;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libflann_cpp.so;debug;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libflann_cpp.so)
-- OpenNI found (include: /usr/include/ni, lib: /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so)
-- OpenNI 2 found (include: /usr/include/openni2, lib: /usr/lib/libOpenNI2.so, redist: )
-- checking for module 'metslib'
--   package 'metslib' not found
-- QHULL found (include: /usr/include, lib: optimized;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libqhull.so;debug;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libqhull.so)
-- VTK_MAJOR_VERSION 5, rendering backend: OpenGL
-- VTK found (include: /usr/include/vtk-5.8;/usr/include, lib: /usr/lib/;/usr/lib)
-- Could NOT find PCAP (missing:  PCAP_LIBRARIES PCAP_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   thread
--   date_time
--   iostreams
--   chrono
-- Found Glew: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLEW.so
-- PCL_EXAMPLES_SUBDIRS /home/ubuntu/pcl/examples/stereo/;/home/ubuntu/pcl/examples/segmentation/;/home/ubuntu/pcl/examples/features/;/home/ubuntu/pcl/examples/outofcore/;/home/ubuntu/pcl/examples/filters/;/home/ubuntu/pcl/examples/keypoints/;/home/ubuntu/pcl/examples/geometry/;/home/ubuntu/pcl/examples/surface/;/home/ubuntu/pcl/examples/common/
-- DOXYGEN_FOUND 
-- HTML_HELP_COMPILER 
-- Found CPack generators: DEB
-- The following subsystems will be built:
--   common
--   ml
--   octree
--   kdtree
--   search
--   sample_consensus
--   filters
--   io
--   2d
--   features
--   registration
--   tracking
--   geometry
--   visualization
--   segmentation
--   people
--   surface
--   recognition
--   stereo
--   keypoints
--   outofcore
--   examples
--   tools
--   apps
       not building: 
       |_ 3d_rec_framework: No reason
       |_ in_hand_scanner: Qt4 is required for the in_hand_scanner app!
       |_ point_cloud_editor: Qt4 was not found.
       |_ cloud_composer: Qt4 was not found.
       |_ optronic_viewer: Qt was not found.
       |_ modeler: Qt4 was not found.
-- The following subsystems will not be built:
--   simulation: Disabled by default.
--   global_tests: No reason
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ubuntu/pcl/build
[  4%] Built target pcl_common
[  5%] Built target pcl_ml
[  5%] Built target pcl_octree
[  5%] Built target pcl_kdtree
[  6%] Built target pcl_search
[  9%] Built target pcl_sample_consensus
[ 16%] Built target pcl_filters
[ 16%] Built target pcl_io_ply
[ 26%] Built target pcl_io
[ 27%] Built target pcl_convert_pcd_ascii_binary
[ 27%] Built target pcl_converter
[ 27%] Built target pcl_hdl_grabber
[ 28%] Built target pcl_openni_grabber_depth_example
[ 28%] Built target pcl_openni_grabber_example
[ 28%] Built target pcl_openni_pcd_recorder
[ 28%] Built target pcl_pcd_convert_NaN_nan
[ 28%] Built target pcl_pcd_introduce_nan
[ 28%] Built target pcl_ply2obj
[ 29%] Built target pcl_ply2ply
[ 29%] Built target pcl_ply2raw
[ 29%] Built target pcl_plyheader
[ 29%] Built target pcl_2d
[ 36%] Built target pcl_features
[ 44%] Built target pcl_registration
[ 45%] Built target pcl_tracking
[ 49%] Built target pcl_visualization
[ 49%] Built target pcl_hdl_viewer_simple
[ 49%] Built target pcl_image_grabber_saver
[ 49%] Built target pcl_image_grabber_viewer
[ 50%] Built target pcl_oni_viewer
[ 50%] Built target pcl_openni2_viewer
[ 50%] Built target pcl_openni_image
[ 50%] Built target pcl_openni_viewer
[ 50%] Built target pcl_pcd_grabber_viewer
[ 51%] Built target pcl_pcd_image_viewer
[ 51%] Built target pcl_timed_trigger_test
[ 52%] Built target pcl_viewer
[ 52%] Built target pcl_vlp_viewer
[ 57%] Built target pcl_segmentation
[ 57%] Built target pcl_people
[ 57%] Built target pcl_ground_based_rgbd_people_detector
[ 62%] Built target pcl_surface
[ 66%] Built target pcl_recognition
[ 67%] Built target pcl_stereo
[ 69%] Built target pcl_keypoints
[ 69%] Built target pcl_outofcore
[ 70%] Built target pcl_outofcore_print
[ 70%] Built target pcl_outofcore_process
[ 71%] Built target pcl_example_stereo_baseline
[ 72%] Built target pcl_example_cpc_segmentation
[ 72%] Built target pcl_example_extract_clusters_normals
[ 72%] Built target pcl_example_lccp_segmentation
[ 72%] Built target pcl_example_region_growing
[ 72%] Built target pcl_example_supervoxels
[ 72%] Built target pcl_example_difference_of_normals
[ 73%] Built target pcl_example_fast_point_feature_histograms
[ 74%] Built target pcl_example_normal_estimation
[ 74%] Built target pcl_example_point_feature_histograms
[ 75%] Built target pcl_example_principal_curvatures_estimation
[ 75%] Built target pcl_example_rift_estimation
[ 76%] Built target pcl_example_shape_contexts
[ 76%] Built target pcl_example_spin_images
[ 76%] Built target pcl_example_outofcore
[ 76%] Built target pcl_example_outofcore_with_lod
[ 76%] Built target pcl_example_extract_indices
[ 76%] Built target pcl_example_remove_nan_from_point_cloud
[ 76%] Built target pcl_example_get_keypoints_indices
[ 76%] Built target pcl_example_sift_keypoint_estimation
[ 76%] Built target pcl_example_sift_normal_keypoint_estimation
[ 76%] Built target pcl_example_sift_z_keypoint_estimation
[ 76%] Built target pcl_example_half_edge_mesh
[ 76%] Built target pcl_example_check_if_point_is_valid
[ 76%] Built target pcl_example_copy_point_cloud
[ 76%] Built target pcl_example_get_max_min_coordinates
[ 76%] Built target pcl_example_organized_point_cloud
[ 76%] Built target pcl_example_scope_time
[ 76%] Built target pcl_add_gaussian_noise
[ 77%] Built target pcl_boundary_estimation
[ 77%] Built target pcl_cluster_extraction
[ 77%] Built target pcl_compute_cloud_error
[ 77%] Built target pcl_compute_hausdorff
[ 77%] Built target pcl_compute_hull
[ 77%] Built target pcl_concatenate_points_pcd
[ 77%] Built target pcl_crf_segmentation
[ 77%] Built target pcl_crop_to_hull
[ 78%] Built target pcl_demean_cloud
[ 78%] Built target pcl_elch
[ 78%] Built target pcl_extract_feature
[ 78%] Built target pcl_fast_bilateral_filter
[ 78%] Built target pcl_fpfh_estimation
[ 78%] Built target pcl_generate
[ 78%] Built target pcl_gp3_surface
[ 78%] Built target pcl_grid_min
[ 79%] Built target pcl_icp
[ 79%] Built target pcl_icp2d
[ 79%] Built target pcl_linemod_detection
[ 80%] Built target pcl_local_max
[ 80%] Built target pcl_lum
[ 80%] Built target pcl_marching_cubes_reconstruction
[ 80%] Built target pcl_match_linemod_template
[ 80%] Built target pcl_mesh2pcd
[ 81%] Built target pcl_mesh_sampling
[ 81%] Built target pcl_mls_smoothing
[ 82%] Built target pcl_morph
[ 82%] Built target pcl_ndt2d
[ 82%] Built target pcl_ndt3d
[ 83%] Built target pcl_normal_estimation
[ 83%] Built target pcl_obj2pcd
[ 83%] Built target pcl_obj2ply
[ 83%] Built target pcl_obj2vtk
[ 83%] Built target pcl_obj_rec_ransac_accepted_hypotheses
[ 84%] Built target pcl_obj_rec_ransac_hash_table
[ 84%] Built target pcl_obj_rec_ransac_model_opps
[ 84%] Built target pcl_obj_rec_ransac_orr_octree
[ 84%] Built target pcl_obj_rec_ransac_orr_octree_zprojection
[ 85%] Built target pcl_obj_rec_ransac_result
[ 85%] Built target pcl_obj_rec_ransac_scene_opps
[ 85%] Built target pcl_octree_viewer
[ 85%] Built target pcl_oni2pcd
[ 85%] Built target pcl_openni_save_image
[ 86%] Built target pcl_organized_pcd_to_png
[ 86%] Built target pcl_outlier_removal
[ 86%] Built target pcl_passthrough_filter
[ 86%] Built target pcl_pcd2ply
[ 87%] Built target pcl_pcd2png
[ 87%] Built target pcl_pcd2vtk
[ 87%] Built target pcl_pcd_change_viewpoint
[ 88%] Built target pcl_pclzf2pcd
[ 88%] Built target pcl_plane_projection
[ 88%] Built target pcl_ply2pcd
[ 88%] Built target pcl_ply2vtk
[ 88%] Built target pcl_png2pcd
[ 89%] Built target pcl_poisson_reconstruction
[ 89%] Built target pcl_progressive_morphological_filter
[ 89%] Built target pcl_radius_filter
[ 89%] Built target pcl_registration_visualizer
[ 89%] Built target pcl_sac_segmentation_plane
[ 89%] Built target pcl_spin_estimation
[ 89%] Built target pcl_tiff2pcd
[ 89%] Built target pcl_train_linemod_template
[ 89%] Built target pcl_train_unary_classifier
[ 90%] Built target pcl_transform_from_viewpoint
[ 90%] Built target pcl_transform_point_cloud
[ 90%] Built target pcl_unary_classifier_segment
[ 90%] Built target pcl_uniform_sampling
[ 90%] Built target pcl_vfh_estimation
[ 90%] Built target pcl_virtual_scanner
[ 90%] Built target pcl_voxel_grid
[ 91%] Built target pcl_voxel_grid_occlusion_estimation
[ 91%] Built target pcl_vtk2obj
[ 91%] Built target pcl_vtk2pcd
[ 91%] Built target pcl_vtk2ply
[ 92%] Built target pcl_xyz2pcd
[ 92%] Built target pcl_apps
[ 92%] Built target pcl_convolve
[ 92%] Built target pcl_dinast_grabber
[ 92%] Built target pcl_face_trainer
[ 93%] Built target pcl_feature_matching
[ 93%] Built target pcl_fs_face_detector
[ 94%] Built target pcl_grabcut_2d
[ 94%] Built target pcl_multiscale_feature_persistence_example
[ 94%] Built target pcl_ni_agast
[ 95%] Built target pcl_ni_brisk
[ 95%] Built target pcl_ni_linemod
[ 95%] Built target pcl_ni_susan
[ 95%] Built target pcl_ni_trajkovic
[ 95%] Built target pcl_nn_classification_example
[ 95%] Built target pcl_openni_3d_concave_hull
[ 95%] Built target pcl_openni_3d_convex_hull
[ 95%] Built target pcl_openni_boundary_estimation
[ 96%] Built target pcl_openni_change_viewer
[ 96%] Built target pcl_openni_face_detector
[ 96%] Built target pcl_openni_fast_mesh
[ 96%] Built target pcl_openni_feature_persistence
[ 96%] Built target pcl_openni_ii_normal_estimation
[ 96%] Built target pcl_openni_klt
[ 97%] Built target pcl_openni_mls_smoothing
[ 97%] Built target pcl_openni_mobile_server
[ 97%] Built target pcl_openni_octree_compression
[ 97%] Built target pcl_openni_organized_compression
[ 97%] Built target pcl_openni_organized_edge_detection
[ 98%] Built target pcl_openni_organized_multi_plane_segmentation
[ 98%] Built target pcl_openni_planar_convex_hull
[ 98%] Built target pcl_openni_planar_segmentation
[ 99%] Built target pcl_openni_shift_to_depth_conversion
[ 99%] Built target pcl_openni_tracking
[ 99%] Built target pcl_openni_uniform_sampling
[ 99%] Built target pcl_openni_voxel_grid
[ 99%] Built target pcl_pcd_organized_edge_detection
[ 99%] Built target pcl_pcd_organized_multi_plane_segmentation
[ 99%] Built target pcl_pcd_select_object_plane
[ 99%] Built target pcl_ppf_object_recognition
[ 99%] Built target pcl_pyramid_surface_matching
[ 99%] Built target pcl_statistical_multiscale_interest_region_extraction_example
[ 99%] Built target pcl_stereo_ground_segmentation
[ 99%] Built target pcl_surfel_smoothing_test
[100%] Built target pcl_test_search_speed
```

What's missing? Can kinfu_large_scale compile for armv7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm building on a Jetson TK1 which is capped at CUDA 6.5 and I've come to the conclusion that kinfu requires > 6.5

Regardless, I found a much better software which is [RTAB-Map](http://introlab.github.io/rtabmap/)